# Why is my tkinter program exiting shortly after it's started?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've started learning Tkinter(some of you may know why). So I made a simple program by following a tutorial:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

myLabel1 = Label(root, text = "Hello Mushroom world!")
myLabel2 = Label(root, text = "Hello Mario world!")
        
myLabel1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
myLabel2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

When I runed it, it showed me a blank window for less than a second and then it disappears (by the way, the window was as big as a restore down window but I think it was supposed to be small because I didn't specify the size of the window). I'm on Windows 10 using WSL2 and I run my code on command prompt because it's a GUI. I would like to know what is causing this bug. Thanks!

Comment: there is no reason for this app to simply close, unless u closed it on purpose. What exactly are you trying to achieve here

Comment: This question title ("What can stop tkinter's mainloop?") is not clear about your actual problem; it implies that you want someone to tell you how to stop the mainloop, not to speculate about why it's stopping without being intended to. "Why is my tkinter program exiting shortly after it's started?" would be more descriptive of what it is that brought you here.

Comment: I want to know why it exited without me telling him to, sorry

Comment: try pasting this code onto Python IDLE and run it from there?

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would cause it to exit. This exact code should work. If the program is crashing, there's probably something wrong with your installation of python and/or tkinter.

Comment: You say you're running it from a command prompt. Does it show any errors once it exits?

Comment: Tkinter is built in not installed, right?

Comment: No, it shows nothing

Comment: Did you name your file `tkinter.py`?

Comment: I named it Tkinter.py

Comment: Oh, so your saying that the name might have been mixed up?

Comment: You should never name a file tkinter.py, or any other module's name, because you are overwriting them. Actually you just replace them, but the outcome is the same.

Comment: Oh your right. It is because of that

Comment: Ok, I understand now, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button that destroys the window, therefore quits the App.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def close_window(): 
    root.destroy()

myLabel1 = Label(root, text = "Hello Mushroom world!")
myLabel2 = Label(root, text = "Hello Mario world!")

button = Button (text = "Close", command = close_window)
        
myLabel1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
myLabel2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
button.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

You can simplify by instead of using the `close_window` function, just type `root.destroy` for the `command` parameter.

#### EDIT

After editing the original question, it turns out the OP's program quit after ~a second, and he wanted to know why does that happen, instead of another way to quit. The error seems to be in his environment. After changing to the original python IDE/IDLE, the code works fine.

Turns out he named his file `tkinter.py`, that caused the bug.

Comment: But I didn't add a button. So why did it dissapear?

Comment: You said you would like to know if there is another way to close your window. There is another way with the button. You have something else as an error?

Comment: I meant, I want to know another way that I might have done accidently. So I can make the window stay longer

Comment: Your code looks cool. This should work, and does work on my machine. Try using Python's default IDE.

Comment: The thing comes with Python. White background editor...

Comment: @JiberJaber the IDLE just type in search bar of ur system

Comment: It works on the interactive command line. SO what's the error here? Why does it exit?

Comment: There is no error in your code. The environment that you used before may have some errors.

Comment: But today I ran the same script on Sublime Text 3. But the code was all in a class and instead of grid() I used pack(). Why did it worked then?

Comment: grid may not pack the element in one environment, but not in another. And elements should be packed.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that it might have not packed?

Comment: I see you named your file tkinter.py, change it to main.py or something, and it should work.